# Exit visual mode without doing an operation

Tags: vim

When I press `[esc]` when I am in visual mode and have a selection highlighted, it outputs:

`recording Q`

What does that mean? And what is the correct way to exit visual mode in vim without doing something like a delete operation?

Comment: You're in [recording mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#recording). It's usually mapped to command `q` in Normal mode, not `<Esc>`.

Comment: You accidentally pressed `q` when trying to reach `<Esc>`. Press `q` again to stop recording.